# Limit of successive approximation

Tags: analysis, limits

I want to calculate the limit when $n\rightarrow \infty$of the successive approximation \begin{equation*}y_{n+1}(x)=1+\int_0^xty_n(t)\, dt\end{equation*} with $y_0(x)=1$, $x\in [-1,1]$.

$$$$

We have that
\begin{align*}&y_0(x)=1 \\ &y_{1}(x)=1+\int_0^xty_0(t)\, dt=1+\int_0^xt\cdot 1\, dt=1+\int_0^xt\, dt=1+\frac{x^2}{2} \\ &y_{2}(x)=1+\int_0^xty_1(t)\, dt=1+\int_0^xt\left (1+\frac{t^2}{2}\right ) \, dt=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}\end{align*} Do we have to find a general formula for $y_{n+1}(x)$ or how can we calculate the limit ?

Comment: If you let $(2n)!! = 2n(2n-2)...2 \cdot 1$, I think you will get find a nice formula which can then be proven rather quickly with induction.

Comment: Thank you!! :-) @Plopperzz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the limit you are going to get 
$$y(x)=1+\int_0^xty(t)dt$$
which under differentiation will give the differential equation:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=x\ y(x)\quad,\quad\mbox{y(0)=1}$$
which can be easily solved to get 
$$y(x)=e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$$
which upon expanding is
$$y(x)=1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{8}+\frac{x^6}{48}+...$$

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you!! :-)